# How to capture downloading address of downloading file?

Tags: browser

I am downloading the file in PC browser so I can easily capture the download link by entering into Downloads Tab & click "copy link address"

In Android, I know by long press on **Download button**, it gives menu so I can use "copy link address" to capture the address.

but **not all sites** display download address in Download tab, I mean **Link address of download button & downloading file are not same**.

so How to capture downloading address in androids OS?

Android OS is 4.2.2

Browser: chrome 30.0.1599.82

Comment: @OP You can try some Download Managers like [ADM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dv.adm) which can capture download links..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better choice for you is try to install third-party download manager, I recommend Loader Droid https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zloy.android.downloader

[image: loader-droid-01]

Comment: Loader Droid capture links by Share menu

Comment: I installed it, but it is not catching downloads like IDM does?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to press and hold on the download button, then press "copy link address" or something similar to that.